# Byte error in regexp

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So, here's the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import exit
import urllib.request

answer = urllib.request.urlopen("http://monip.org").read()

def debug(txt):
    print(txt)
    exit(0)

def parse_answer(answer):
    ''' Simple function to parse request's HTML result
        to find the ip in it. Raise RuntimeError if no 
        ip in result and ip else.
    '''
    import re
    pattern = "^\w+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\w+$"
    regexp = re.compile(pattern)
    if regexp.match(regexp, answer):
        m = regexp.search(regexp, answer)
        ip = m.group(0)
        return ip
    else:
        raise RuntimeError

try:
    ip = parse_answer(answer)
except RuntimeError:
    print("Error, check your network configuration.")
    print("Aborting..")
    exit(1)

print("IP:", ip)
```

I wrote that. This code is intended to give you your public ip adress. It throws a RunTime error if it cannot give you anything.

And here's the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./ippub", line 27, in 
>       ip = parse_answer(answer)
>     File "./ippub", line 19, in parse_answer
>       if regexp.match(regexp, answer):
>   TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

That means "answer" variable is bytes, but I wanna match an ip adress in it, and I can't because of python type system :-)

Any idea ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate problems.

1. You need to convert `answer` to a string, even though `answer` has some funny characters that do not decode well with `utf-8`.
2. You are invoking the regular expressions API incorrectly.

Here is a corrected version, which uses `chr` to work around issue 1, and fixes issue 2 with the correct syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import exit
import urllib.request
import re


def debug(txt):
    print(txt)
    exit(0)

def parse_answer(answer):
    ''' Simple function to parse request's HTML result
        to find the ip in it. Raise RuntimeError if no 
        ip in result and ip else.
    '''
    answer = "".join([chr(x) for x in answer])
    pattern = "(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
    regexp = re.compile(pattern)
    m = regexp.search(answer)
    if m:
        ip = m.group(0)
        return ip
    else:
        raise RuntimeError

answer = urllib.request.urlopen("http://monip.org").read()

try:
    ip = parse_answer(answer)
except RuntimeError:
    print("Error, check your network configuration.")
    print("Aborting..")
    exit(1)

print("IP:", ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll try to:

```
print answer
```

you'll fail because it's encoded in `ISO-8859-1`.

You should convert it first to `UTF-8` before sending it to `parse_answer()`:

```
answer = answer.encode('utf8')
```

Once you'll pass that hurdle you'll run into another error which relies in the following two lines:

```
if regexp.match(regexp, answer):
    m = regexp.search(regexp, answer)
```

since `regex` is already a compiled pattern, you shouldn't send it as an argument in any of the two calls above! change the code to:

```
if regexp.match(answer):
    m = regexp.search(answer)
```

and it should work!

---

***For Merlin:***

```
import requests
answer = requests.get("http://monip.org")
print answer.text.encode('utf8')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>MonIP.org v1.0</title>
<META http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<P ALIGN="center"><FONT size=8><BR>IP : 50.184.3.115<br></font><font size=3><i>c-50-184-3-115.hsd1.ca.comcast.net</i><br></font><font size=1><br><br>Pas de proxy détecté - No Proxy detected</font></html>
```

Comment: @merlin2011 I *did* test this solution and I'll post the code in a minute (especially for you ;)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. Your method of calling the requests library is completely different from the OP's method, so your answer is now much more useful. +1.